# How to run "Grunt serve" command on live hosting?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, gruntjs, nodes

I have made one angular app. this app in use grunt and run application using "Grunt Serve" command. But, I have uploads this application on live hosting. so, please help me... How to run "Grunt serve" command on live hosting?

Comment: you need to install grunt on your hosting and then using ssh you have to run grunt serve

Comment: where is your app hosted?

Answer (score 0):

Achieve that by following steps:

- Make sure *node.js* is installed on hosting instance
- Make sure you app has proper `package.json` that contains grunt
  dependencies used by your app
- Connect to host machine and run `npm install` (via *putty* or *ssh* or
  ....)
- After packages are installed you can run `grunt serve` manually or you
  can put that command in `postinstall` script of `package.json` to auto
  run after `npm install` is done